# I want to get a list of all files in a target directory including subdirectories, with the path starting at the target directory

Tags: python, arrays, recursion, path

I want to get a list of all files in a target directory including subdirectories, with the path starting at the target directory.

edit1:
I want to insert it at the correct position alphabetically.

```
$ tree test
test
├── file
└── sub
    ├── fileinsub
    ├── otherfileinsub
    └── sub2
        └── fileinsub2
```

```
>>> print(os.listdir("test"))
['sub', 'file']
>>>print(recusivelistdir("test"))
['sub', 'sub/fileinsub', 'sub/otherfileinsub', 'sub/sub2', 'sub/sub2/fileinsub2' 'file']
```

edit8: My previous solution wasn't a solution at all. I wrote a new function that does work, though.

````py
def reclsdir(target: str):
    """
    Takes a target directory and returns a list of files in that directory, recursing through subdirectories.

    Mirrors `os.listdir()`.

    example:
 
    ```
    $ tree test
    test
    ├── fileintest
    └── sub
        ├── fileinsub
        ├── otherfileinsub
        ├── sub2
        │   └── fileinsub2
        └── sub3

    print(reclsdir("test"))
    # ['sub', 'sub/fileinsub', 'sub/sub2', 'sub/sub2/fileinsub2', 'sub/otherfileinsub', 'sub/sub3', 'fileintest']
    ```
    """
    list = [f"{target}/{i}" for i in os.listdir(target)]
    i = 0
    list_len = len(list)
    while i < list_len:
        if os.path.isdir(list[i]) == True:
            sublist = [f"{list[i]}/{n}" for n in os.listdir(list[i])]
            for n in range(len(sublist)):
                list.insert(i + 1 + n, sublist[n])
            list_len = len(list)
        i = i + 1
    # Remove 'target/' from every item, making func consistent with `os.listdir()`
    return [x.removeprefix(target + "/") for x in list] # ex: 'test/sub' -> 'sub'
````

Comment: "os.walk" can help here.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
def recusivelistdir(path):
    result = []
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
         result.extend([root + os.path.sep + _dir for _dir in dirs])
         result.extend([root + os.path.sep + file for file in files])
    print(result)
recusivelistdir('path folder')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always made a recursive solution, but in this case the `os` module have a good method, `os.walk(path)`, where `path` is the root directory

```py
li=[]
for d,ds,fs in os.walk(path):
    li+=[f"{d}/{f}" for f in fs] 
return li
```

Inside the for, `d` will be the current directory, `ds` a list of all subdirectories inside `d` and `fs` the list of all files inside `d`, in every iteration of the for, the method "walks" inside the subdirectories inside the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use glob you will love it!

```
from glob import glob
target = "test" + <REG_EX>
target_files = glob(target, recursive=True)
```

Replace REG_EX with whatever the sub_dir string you need.

To elaborate more on the solution use `sorted` on glob output to sort the directories any type necessary

```
sorted(glob.glob('./test/**/*',recursive=True)) #Sorts alphabetically.
```

If you need more sorting;

```
sorted(glob.glob(('./test/**/*',recursive=True),key=os.path.getmtime) # Sorts with mt time
sorted(glob.glob(('./test/**/*',recursive=True),key=os.path.getsize) # Sorts with size
```