# Fastest way to search many files in many directories?

Tags: python, file, search, directory

I have a list of file names

```
files = (
    "myinstruction.txt",
    "myinfo.txt",
    "mydata.txt",
    "myclients.txt",
    "foo.txt",
)
```

and a set of directories where the files *might* be contained (path might lead to nested structure)

```
search_paths = (
   "C:/Users/Foo/Desktop/thisfolder/",
   "F:/Documents/mylibrary/",
   "F:/Folder/mylibrary/",
   "E:/Otherfolder/foolibrary/",
)
```

What is the **most optimized** function we could create to find back the full paths of our files?

Comment: Have a look at `os.walk()`.

Comment: you can use the `os.walk()` function, here is a little example, you can modify it and set some conditionals, https://stackoverflow.com/a/74090639/12677411

Comment: Do you need to examine sub-directories? Also, what do you want as a result? I'm guessing you want a list of the full paths where the files are found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multithreading would be ideal for this.

Firstly, make the tuple of filenames into a set for faster searching.

Then it's as simple as...

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import os

FILES = {
    "myinstruction.txt",
    "myinfo.txt",
    "mydata.txt",
    "myclients.txt",
    "foo.txt"
}

SEARCH_PATHS = [
   "C:/Users/Foo/Desktop/thisfolder/",
   "F:/Documents/mylibrary/",
   "F:/Folder/mylibrary/",
   "E:/Otherfolder/foolibrary/"
]

def process_directory(directory):
    output = []
    for root, _, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            if file in FILES:
                output.append(os.path.join(root, file))
    return output

result = []

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for rv in executor.map(process_directory, SEARCH_PATHS):
        result.extend(rv)

print(result)
```

In this way, each directory will be examined in a separate (concurrent) thread. As os.walk() is I/O bound, multithreading is appropriate

Comment: That's exactly what i was searching for, thank you very much
is this solution cross-platform compatible?

Comment: @DB3D Yes - this will work on Windows or any Unix/BSD style platform

Answer (score 0):

As per comments, you can utilize [os.walk()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm)
Unless you are using memoization, I'm not sure there's a faster way than this

Example code:

```
import os

file_list = (
    "myinstruction.txt",
    "myinfo.txt",
    "mydata.txt",
    "myclients.txt",
    "foo.txt",
)

search_paths = (
   "C:/Users/Foo/Desktop/thisfolder/",
   "F:/Documents/mylibrary/",
   "F:/Folder/mylibrary/",
   "E:/Otherfolder/foolibrary/",
)

# search for files inside search_paths using os.walk()
for path in search_paths:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if file in file_list:
                print(os.path.join(root, file))
```